# Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email attachment using action mailer in ruby on rails and I keep getting this error. The problem seems to be that it can't locate the file in the directory I specified, but the file path is valid. I also checked this using `File.exist?` in the console and confirmed that the path provided evaluates to true.

Here is my mailer:

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer   
  def purchase(order)
    @order = order
    attachments[ 'files.zip'] = File.read(Rails.root + '/public/albums/files.zip')
    mail to: order.email, subject: "Order Confirmation"
  end
end
```

I also installed the mail gem to handle encoding, as advised by the Action Mailer documentation.

Any help would be much appreciated,
-Brian

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605782/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-ruby

Answer (score 10):

`Rails.root` returns a `Pathname` object. `Pathname#+(string)` will `File.join` the `string` to the path *if it is relative*; if `string` represents an absolute path (i.e. starts with a slash), the path gets *replaced*.

```
Pathname.new('/tmp') + 'foo'
# => #<Pathname:/tmp/foo> 
Pathname.new('/tmp') + '/foo'
# => #<Pathname:/foo>
```

This means, you are reading from the wrong path: you wanted to read `/path/to/app/public/albums/files.zip`, but you are actually reading `/public/albums/files.zip`, which likely shouldn't exist.

Solution: make sure you are appending the relative path:

```
Rails.root + 'public/albums/files.zip'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Rails.root returns path object. So you need toconvert it to string to concatenate it with another string as follows:
(**Rails.root.to_s** + '/public/albums/files.zip')